# How can I get the http request headers actually sent by me in node.js http request

Tags: node.js, http, http-headers, request, httprequest

Here's my simplified code:

```
var request = http.request(options);
request.on('response', function( res ) {
    console.log("response received");
});
request.end();
```

I would like to print out the actually sent request headers (I assume that node adds some itself) How can I get them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It lives in the request object, which can be found in the response `res.req._header`. It's helpful to use node-inspector to inspect these objects in real time.

```
request.on('response', function( res ) {
  console.log(res.req._header);
  console.log("response received");
});
```